# Ubercart override default flat rate quote

Tags: ubercart

Drupal 7.  Using Ubercart 7.x-3.10.  I created a shipping default flat rate quote of $7.  I created a product and gave it a flat shipping rate of $3.00.  When I check out, the shipping quote is $10 (default + product).  I don't understand how I get the product flat rate quote to override the default flat rate quote.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I discovered is that in order for the default shipping flat rate quote to be overridden by product flat rate quote:

In Configuration->shipping quotes:
**Base price** must be set to 0.00
**Default product shipping rate** set to whatever the flat rate is.  In my example, it was $7.00.

In product ->shipping settings->flat shipping rates:
**Flat rate quotes** should be set to the overriding amount.  In my example, it was $3.00.

So, in the test product example, the flat quote shipping rate would be $3.00.  If no rate is set in the product, then the rate will be the default shipping quote of $7.00.

A bit confusing at first, but logical, I guess.